# Проверить свойства контекстно свободного языка

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Проверить свойства контекстно свободного языка.
L=(b^n(ab)^m*ba^n*b^m|n>=1,m>=1}
 Точное описания выражения на скриншоте[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите пожалуйста правильно ли я решаю его.
Контекстно свободный язык это язык который имеет свойства ,что левая часть это нетерминалы ,а правая любой символ.

```
S−>ABCDK
A−>b|AA
B−>BB|ab
C−>b
D−>DD|a
K−>KK|b
```

У меня получилось составить правило грамматике по этому выражению,значит язык является контекстно свободным и его свойства выполняются?

пример вывода цепочки по этой грамматики которая у меня получилась

```
S−>ABCDK−>bBCDK−>babCDK−>babbDK−>ba bbaK−>babbab
```

Кажется понял где моя ошибка рассмотрим два слова (ab)^m и b^m по лемме о накачке (ab)^m+k не равно b^m значит есть протеворечие и язык не контекстно свободный так доказывается?

Comment: Не очень я большой специалист, но что-то в памяти сидит, что КС грамматики не умеют считать - т.е. вот это n и m делает грамматику не КС. Но как это доказывать - не подскажу...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBTKqvqGZ6Q&feature=youtu.be&t=282